# How to get value of returned variable inside function to initState?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a function setPlayer which returns a value of _controller(this is value of YoutubePlayerController).

```
  YoutubePlayerController _controller;

  YoutubePlayerController setPlayer(index) {
    _controller = YoutubePlayerController(
      initialVideoId: YoutubePlayer.convertUrlToId(videoID[index]),
      flags: YoutubePlayerFlags(autoPlay: false),
    );

    return _controller;
  }
```

I call this function to get a value of my youtube link(this is array of youtube URLs) and that works.

```
YoutubePlayer(controller: setPlayer(index))
```

I want when I press button for navigation to next screen to pause video but it doesn't stop.

```
 onTap: () {
   deactivate();

   Navigator.push(
    context,
    new MaterialPageRoute(
      builder: (context) => new CameraScreen(),
     ),
    );
   },
```

This is my deactivate function but I don't get the value of controller and video doesn't want stop.

```
 @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void deactivate() {
    print('xdxdxdxd');
    print(_controller);
    super.deactivate();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller.dispose();
    _controller.pause();
    super.dispose();
  }
```

I tried move value to init state but I cant define index. Any possible way to controller save the value when it is pass to deactivate function.

Comment: deactivate is a function inside your YoutubePlayerController ?

Answer (score 0):

On dispose method you are calling dispose on controller before pause call, swap them :

```
@override
  void dispose() {
    _controller.pause();
    _controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
```

You can try call it like this:

```
MaterialPageRoute(
      builder: (context) {
_controller.pause();
 return CameraScreen();},
```

Comment: Still doesn't work. I did not call this dispose method before but I tried right now and still nothing.

Comment: thanks for answer but still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

does deactivate() work? i.e prints xdxdxdxd to console?

why don't you just try

```
  onTap: () {
   _controller.pause();

   Navigator.push(
    context,
    new MaterialPageRoute(
      builder: (context) => new CameraScreen(),
     ),
    );
   },
```

Comment: I get this when call a deactivate()   https://prnt.sc/10qd75x
I expect values for each of this properties but I get nothing.